# update database entry and/or preserve exisisting entries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building a PHP application that checks the birthdays of the users in my database.
These users are granted a variety of gifts at their birthday, from which they may pick one. I keep track of which they picked, so I can see who has claimed a gift and who still has a gift waiting.

The target group of this application are companies, who pay a fee per employee that is part of this application. The application is made to make it easier for companies to remember their employees birthdays and show they care.

As the companies grow/shrink, as they are hiring, firing employees, they are to update their employee list every month so the system is able to exclude those who no longer work there and add new employees.

Now my question is: How do I do this the smartest way?

If I were to remove every employee that previously was associated with a given company, when given their current employee roster, and insert the new list from scratch, I would loose the association between an employee and an un/claimed gift in my database.

On the other hand, to make sure I preserve the association in my database, if I were to only add new employees and remove those who are no longer on the roster, how would I go about this the smartest way?

The fields I got on the employees are `id`, `firstname`, `surname`, `email`, `birthday` and `company_id`. Neither of these would be a good way to identify whether the user already is in the database (can argue that the email might work, but if for some reason they changed it, it wouldn't work)

Any suggestions are more then welcome.

Comment: Tip: Cut short your question, else users will run away

Comment: You need several things. One is a flag against the user to say if they're an active employee or not and then when you're looking for people to give stuff to just select where active=1 (or whatever you call your field). The other thing is on your new list import instead of deleting the users no longer there look for something to compare to if you don't get passed a unique employee ID from the company I suggest matching on email address of user as they should be unique per user and if they aren't in the new imported list set their active flag to zero.

Comment: Nice, that sounds like a good way to do it, thanks!

Comment: Surely any company large enough to want and need to keep track of things is going to have Outlook or something similar, which already does this - so where does this product fit in?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is to add `employee_id` to your database.  Every company has internal IDs they use to identify employees internally within their system.  This is necessary for many purposes, including payroll, benefits, attendance, etc.  Therefore all you need is to add this `ID` field to your `employee` table and ensure that the roster you receive contains these IDs for all employees.

In addition, rather than deleting entries for employees that no longer work for the company, you can just have a flag indicating whether the employment is still active.  Then add a corresponding `where` clause to your queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a simple field to your table employee:

```
employeeID | name | isStillHired
```

when a company fires an employee you set to false the field `isStillHired` in this way you don't lose the references for him

Comment: Sounds like a plan! I will flag this as the awnser when i can, thanks